# jQuery ajax related error

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am having some trouble with an ajax jquery call.

```
function postSomeData() {
    console.log("LOG: in f'n postSomeData");
    $.ajax({
        url:api_endpoint,
        type:'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic " + auth_encoded);
        },
        data:some_data,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("derp");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, statusText, errorThrown) {
            console.log("herp");
        }
    });
}
```

This code is supposed to run every few minutes (Edit:The log statement appears every minute as expected), however no callback is ever executed and the server never registers a request. The code just before the the ajax function runs and other functions use a very similar format also execute (the only difference is what data gets sent), I am unable to determine why.

If I try to force the code to run several times I sometimes get this error:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'obj' [null] is not an object.
```

Notes: This is happening with jquery 1.7.1, jquery mobile 1.0, phonegap 1.1.0 on the ios 4.3 emulator. Debugging done with weinre.

**EDIT:**

`api_endpoint` is a string with the to the http address of the server (for development, my computers IP address.

`obj` is not an object I have created, the only object I have created is `some_data`

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the contents of 'some_data'.

```
{"coords":{"latitude":43,"longitude":-79,"altitude":0,"accuracy":150,"heading":-1,"speed":0,"altitudeAccuracy":-1},"timestamp":13232}
```

Comment: *"This code is supposed to run every few minutes, however no callback is ever executed"* The code you've quoted only shows the ajax call, not how you're making it happen every few minutes, which is probably relevant. Similarly, the error you've shown doesn't do us any good without seeing where and how you're using `obj`. And it would be useful to know what's in `api_endpoint`.

Comment: The console statement just before runs every minute, so I suspect the error message comes from within the jquery library. I see `obj` referenced several times, but haven't been to thoroughly grok it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Firebug's Net tab to confirm that a request is being made in the first place?  Perhaps your URL is incorrect?  Try setting the `timeout` of the Ajax call and see if the `error` callback is working.

Comment: I am not running the application in a standard web browser, there is enough functionality on the application that trying to run in a standard web browser is not possible (Same Origin Policy, Cross Site Scripting etc) without doing some major overhaul as well as setting up a proxy of some kind. Setting the timeout value to a few seconds has not changed any of the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Working a bit in the dark here (see my comment on the question), but if `api_endpoint` contains a URL that isn't on the same **origin** as the page in which this code is running, you could be hitting the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction — I haven't done any Phonegap programming, I don't know whether or to what extent the SOP applies. [This article](http://www.romkey.com/2011/04/23/getting-around-same-origin-policy-in-web-browsers/) says that Phonegap disables the SOP on Mobile Safari; I have no idea whether it does/can for the other platforms it supports.

Comment: PhoneGap doesn't disable the SOP. However, there is no SOP when you load your resources from the file:// protocol on Android, iOS or BlackBerry web views. This is what PhoneGap takes advantage of.

Comment: As Simon says, there is no SOP issues on a web view, but if I were in a normal browser a SOP violation gives a much more descriptive error message.

Comment: @CoatedMoose: Not usually, no. On a lot of browsers, you just get back a blank response with `null` as the response body.

Comment: I meant that within Firebug and the debugger with Chromium, the error is very explicit ("Request not allowed due to Same Origin Policy" - or something similar). I have encountered several times during my initial construction of my application while testing in the standard web browser.

Comment: @CoatedMoose: Quite true with Firebug or Chromium.